# Looking for software such as ZipRepair or WinRAR that can repair files by command line or API

Tags: windows, zip

I'm looking for a way to repair a zip file that can be automated or scripted, such as through a command line or API. I've looked at a number of zip repair utilities, and searched through windows utilities. There is software available that will do it, of course, but it only seems to be available through a software application user interface.

I could probably automate through software UI - I've done that sort of thing before - but that's pretty ugly

Comment: I have written code for my own needs that can recover damaged zip files, such as when some bytes in the file were overwritten. But it's not ready for the mass market, if that's what you're looking for. Can you give me some insight on what kind of damages you expect to repair? Do you have sample files? Why do you need to automate this, i.e. why do you expect to need this regularly? If I can see a good reason for this, I might just put in a few hours and make my tool available as a cmdline tool or something similar.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! As this site is about recommending software (not how-tos): could you please **[edit]** your question and include what OS the recovery software must run on, and how much you'd be willing to pay if it came to paid solutions?

Comment: @Izzy can't answer how much we'd be willing to pay.  Depends on options and licensing and talking to those higher up.